# How to quit from a looper?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
1. Looper.prepare();
2. Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
3. public void handleMessage(Message msg) {}
4. };
5. mHandler.post(gpsLocationListenerThread);
6. Looper.loop();
7.
```

I'm calling a `Thread` class from `AsyncTask`. When i call it using code from 1-6, it creates the `Thread` and runs it. But `AsyncTask` get stucked there. I need to run this other `Thread` without blocking my `AsyncTask`. How to make it happen?

```
public GPSLocationListenerThread(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    mlocManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mlocListener = new GPSLocationListener();
}

public void setHandler(Handler _h){
    this.mHandler = _h;
}

public void run(){
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 100, mlocListener); // in 1000 mseconds or in 100m change
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 100, mlocListener); // in 1000 mseconds or in 100m change
    //mHandler.getLooper().quit();
    while (DataHolder.getDataHolderObject().isTripStarted()){
        try {
            this.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
}
```

Comment: 9 times out of 10 there is no need to call a Thread from an AsyncTask What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I need to start the GPS Location listener depends on some other variable changers. AsyncTask is listening to those changers. But GPS Litener cannot be started from AsncTask either.

Comment: If you quit looper your thread will be stopped.

Comment: How to keep the thread running and also AsyncTask Running

Comment: an asynctask listening ? like polling for changes ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to call Looper.quit(); anyway or it will never quit. Where you need to call it i have no idea unless you post a bit more code :)

Comment: I tried to call it at line 7, but i think it do not move to line 7 until the thread finishes.

Comment: Can you post the gpsLocationListenerThread class? or at least parts of it if it's confidential

Comment: I added the whole class. I have commented out one single line i tired. But it didnt work

Comment: can you try adding this:  
try {
            Log.i("asd","here"); this.sleep(5000); 
    }

Comment: i tired it. It keeps waking up every 5 seconds. Nothing has happened from the quit command.

Comment: Well, the first thing that comes to mind would be having the sleep(5000) just before/after mHandler.post(gpsLocationListenerThread);. But i'm not really sure tbh :/ sorry

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the documentation, it's not always needed to quit a looper.
And if you insist - you must call it on the same thread of the looper.
See my elaborate answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20134464/1180898).